# How to use impoly with msgbox in matlab gui?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

**Requirement :**
I am creating a matlab gui project. I have a `pushbutton` in my code, when clicked creates a `figure` displaying an image from the parent GUI with a `msgbox` as a popup. After clicking `ok` on the `msgbox` I want to select the region of interest using `impoly` command.

**Problem**:
Now the problem is after clicking the `ok` button on the `msgbox` the `impoly` command doesn't work. The mouse pointer doesn't change into a selector. I have searched the matlab documentation and the alternate is `warndlg` but the same happens.

**Here is my code :**

```
% --- Executes on button press in roi.
function roi_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to roi (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
image=getimage(handles.axes2);    % acquire image from parent gui
figure;                           % figure;
msgbox('Select ROI for overlapped area','overlapped region');   %message box
im=imshow(image);      % to show the image in figure;
data12=impoly;         % creates a roi polygon selector
mask12=createMask(data12,im); % creates a binary mask
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the `msgbox` within the [uiwait](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiwait.html) function.

This allows blocking the execution of the callbak until the user press the OK button.

```
% msgbox('Select ROI for overlapped area','overlapped region'));   %message box
uiwait(msgbox('Select ROI for overlapped area','overlapped region'));   %message box
```

Hope this helps.
Qapla'

Comment: You're welcome! In order to close the question youi might want to mark the answer as accepted.